# how to check username and password in login route after finishing register post with pgadmin4 in vs code

Tags: javascript, html

this is my backend code now

[image]

this is my login front end

[image]

what should I do?

Comment: Hi there, instead of posting images of your code, you should post the actual text of the code instead, and [format it](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: don't save the password in clear text in the database, use a hash and salt, on login hash the password given (by https) and check if it is found in the database, if yes set a cookie with a sessionID and userID, and expire time, at each request check cookie and set new cookie with updated expire time

Comment: why tag with VSC? Can you do it in vim or notepad?

Comment: what JavaScript framework do you use? add that as a tag